# Chunks of tooltips get stuck, where the screen isn't refreshing, I guess. (Windows 7 Professional x64, 1-2 monitors)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Here's a screenshot: 
[image: screenshot tooltips stuck]

It happens a lot, not always. This screenshot was taken after less than an hour of browsing web, searching for something desperately, a lot of mouse movement, plus working on something else, don't remember what software. If I'd press start, for example, the whole top area would get cleaned.

It doesn't happen only near the taskbar, for example, if a tooltip from a software would start showing up while I'd use alt-tab to switch to another application, then it will still show up and stay there on the screen until I'd move my mouse over it.

Usually, I reboot my laptop only when I'll update my Windows, in other cases I'll just put it to sleep or hibernate. I often switch between 1 and 2 monitors setup. Sometimes I play video games in fullscreen.

This problem has been there since I installed my copy of Windows, a few years ago, I believe. Googled then, didn't find anything, googled now, still nothing. It's not an urgent matter but it got me too curious already.

*some specs: Windows 7 x64 Pro - up to date; Acer Extensa 5630g laptop, ATI Mobility HD 3650 (original driver that came with the CD, for my laptop; Please don't tell me to update since the new drivers can get really really buggy), Intel core2duo T5800*

**EDIT :**

- Added bounty.
- Please offer an explanation as of why is this happening, and a solution if it exists. I'm not looking only for a way to *hide* the problem.
- Just a reminder: chunks of tooltips get stuck on margins (as seen in the screenshot), also, a whole tooltip may get stuck in the center of the screen if I switch fast between applications.

**EDIT2 :**

- Three days remaining until I have to award the bounty and as I don't see any trustworthy answer, at least guide me to where else I could ask this. My Windows copy is a MSDNAA licensed one, I got the key for being a student in a Romanian faculty that is registered in the program. I'm not sure I have any other official support from Microsoft except their representative in my faculty whom I can't reach in the next few months to, maybe, a year from now on, and I'm not sure he'll be able to help me whatsoever.

Comment: If you are hesitant to update the graphics card drivers, how can we be sure the drivers are *not* the problem?

Comment: Because the driver that came with my laptop should work, was tested etc. on my system specifically. I tried updating the drivers 2 times when they released 2 new versions, from the AMD website, both times I ended up reinstalling my windows. The only drivers that work are: 1) that comes with windows, 2) the one found on the acer support website (same as on my old CD)

Comment: Did your laptop come with the same version of Windows that you have now?

Comment: It came with a linux distro, forgot which. I'm running a MSDNAA Windows now, I guess it's no different than a standard licensed one except that I don't have support.

Comment: @vzait While doing all manners of customisations of windows 7 Desk, testing both the "classic" views and "Aero", with toolbars, gadgets, and changes to the borders and other things. I am getting some of the same things. There are a LOT of bugs in the thing, just try and do things off the "norm". Sometimes I am just happy that they dont fix them with constant refreshes , or some other poor method to post patch it. I really think it has more to do with the new display methods, more than how the video cards are rendering it. but it could certannly be a combo.

Comment: I don't think at all that it's a rendering bug, it shouldn't be. I just posted the info in case I'm wrong since I don't know much about how windows works. It just got me curious as of why is it happening, and it certainly won't change my attitude towards windows if there is no simple known solution. After all, I lived happily with this bug since I remember switching to Win7 :)

Comment: Example: Did anyone notice the Huge space wasting borders on the windows ? It is adjustable in the advanced display properties. once the border size is reduced to normal, what it was "Hiding" :-) is revealed.  Anyone notice that Gadgets, have been tossed? Hit the gadget button and try and go to windows gadget site.  MSes own Toobars, around since win98 tossed. We got the pretty cute stuff, but for some reason all the Working parts , are tossed. I am beginning to see a pattern.

Comment: @vzait, if you want to try a fix, go into the advanced display options (windows color) and adjust the border padding.

Comment: But it still leaves the tooltips that get stuck on the screen when switching between applications.

Comment: Then there are 2 more adjustments, the "window border" itself, and the size of the bar itself, and icons in it. it is said that changing the DPI changes the icon size also ??  In your picture is it showing the start button is wider than the taskbar button items?

Comment: Vzait - The Acer support page for the Acer Extensa 5630g shows that it shipped with Windows Vista - AND that it has a ATI Mobility HD 3470: http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2008/acer/Extensa/Extensa5630G/Extensa5630Gsp2.shtml
So you are using a Vista driver for Windows 7?
It also shows that the HD3470 uses shared memory (has built-in and shared). Maybe you could raise the amount of shared memory to see if that allows those artifacts to clear?

Comment: @vzait: Do you use Chrome by any chance?

Comment: @WinOutreach4 I really don't know where did you get that page from, maybe those are the specs for another country etc. I bought mine in Romania, it shipped with a linux distro, and a dedicated HD 3650 video card. And I'm not even sure if Windows 7 lets you use unsigned drivers without tweaking it first. I got all my drivers from acer's support website, for my Win 7 Pro x64.

Comment: @Mehrdad sometimes. Why is this important?

Comment: @vzait: Well, I've noticed that Chrome sometimes doesn't paint correctly, and the windows in front of it or behind it sometimes show through. I'm wondering if you're seeing this problem only when you use Chrome?

Comment: @Mehrdad I just tested. Chrome has nothing to do with this problem, Chrome displays the tooltips INSIDE HIS window, unlike firefox, or other applications.

Comment: @vzait: Okay never mind then.

Comment: @vzait: That would probably explain the difference then. That page is the US Acer site. I know you have heard this and don't want to do it, but updating the video driver would really help to prove if this in an issue with your driver or not.

Comment: @WinOutreach4 My system has been stable for over a year and a half now, except for this small bug. That's why I'm so hesitant in installing a new driver that hasn't been recommended by acer, otherwise they'd just upload the new driver on their website. I know, it might be a bug that has been fixed in the newer version, but at the same time it might bring some other serious bugs. Let's not forget that the video card is kinda old and if I'd be the one at AMD designing a new driver I'd concentrate my efforts on newer devices, on desktop computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of changes to GDI in Windows Vista, Windows 7 and how applications use GDI to draw on window device contexts. The applications can change how they draw and Microsoft can make changes to improve things.

To just redraw the screen without any artifacts press the WindowsKey+D twice.

Answer (score 3):

I know you didn't want to hear this... but sadly, this appears to be a bad driver issue (if you're lucky)... or a failing video-card (if you're not so lucky).  With Windows 7, Microsoft has gone to great lengths to implement a lot more DirectX into their GUI which means it uses the native graphics drivers' methods to render a great deal more on the screen.  If the driver doesn't properly implement transparency and alpha-channels correctly, you'll see screen-artifacts remaining behind when you close/minimize an application.

This can be caused when Windows tells the driver to draw the nice transparent area (that you have pointed out)... and the rendering function errors... due to hardware or software problems.  Windows silently eats the error, but instead of rendering a nice transparent area... it leaves whatever random graphic buffer data there... which usually resembles whatever was there previously.

Disabling the "Aero" features in Windows 7 may make the problem less noticeable... but you would lose all the shiney-graphics windows 7 adds.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I'm using the classic look mostly. When enabling "Aero", the problem goes away. Ok, let's call those chunks of tooltips that get stuck on the taskbar an artifact. How about the tooltips that get stuck in the center of the screen? I can get a stuck tooltip even when watching a movie in vlc. Shouldn't the buffer be refreshed at this point? And what nice transparent area I have pointed out?

Comment: Still could be both a bad driver and/or failing video card.  In short... when a render instruction fails... windows will silently eat the error and just move on to the next step in rendering.  Ideally yes, the screen should get refreshed... but if there are errors re-drawing the screen... you're going to have artifacts like you describe.